# How to select records between two timestamps in oracle

Tags: oracle, select, timestamp

I have a table where the column `recorded`is defined as a `timestamp` as follows:

```
 TIMESTAMP(6) RECORDED
```

I want to select all the records which have been "recorded" between 2 timestamps . For that I wrote the following query:

```
    SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE
    recorded BETWEEN 1414794711050 AND 1415399511053;
```

When doing this I am getting an error

ORA-00932: Inconsistent Data types: TIMESTAMP expected, NUMBER got
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

I also tried with:

```
    SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 
    recorded BETWEEN to_timestamp(1414794711) AND to_timestamp(1415399511);
```

How is the way get this query working?

Comment: Is "1414794711050" a unix-timestamp? (seconds from 1 Jan 1970)

Comment: It is the amount of milliseconds from 1 Jan 1970, but it would be no problem to take the amount of seconds, i.e. dividing by 1000 and truncating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE recorded BETWEEN to_date('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') + 1414794711050/24/60/60/1000
                   and to_date('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') + 1415399511053/24/60/60/1000;
```

`1414794711050/24/60/60/1000` converts milliseconds to a number of days (24 hours in a day, 60 munites in a hour, 60 seconds in a minute)

`to_date('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD')` + [N days] = new date (N days later)